# Consle Error running react-native application on expo-cli

Tags: javascript, react-native, emulation, expo

I've been working on a android application using react-native and expo, I tried to start the app and get this error on the expo mobile app.[Error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNnNj.jpg)

```
Console.error: "There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment", Error: Out of memory
```

I've tried restarting the application and clearing the cache with `shift + r`.
But still get the Same error, wanted to know if anyone could help??.

Before trying to contact expo support directly

Comment: I'd start by removing any console.logs you have to see if that at least lets the app run